# Are there any functions that satisfy these properties?

Tags: calculus, special-functions, functional-equations, periodic-functions

You're given a function $f$ : $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy these properties
$$ f(x +1)=f(x), f(n + \dfrac{1}{2})=1, f(n)=0  \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Are there any functions $m,n$ : $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy

$$ m(x) \neq 0 \ \ \text{with all $x$ satisfy} \ \ f(x)=m(x)(n(x) + 1) $$

Comment: $m(x)=f(x),n(x)=0$

Comment: $m(x)\neq 0$ means that answer does not work for $x = n$.

Comment: @JoshuaWang I thought he wanted to say $m(x)$ is not zero function.

Comment: No, I'm not given a function. I'm given a homework that isn't *my* homework.

Comment: @PNDas I meant for all x that satisfy f(x)=m(x).(n(x)+1) : m(x) is not zero

Comment: Very similar but closed question with no answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905929/i-want-someone-to-help-me-solve-this-mystry

Answer (score 2):

Note that $n(x) = f(x) - 1$, $m(x) = 1$ satisfy the conditions of the problem. Here is a specific example of $f(x), n(x), m(x)$that work for $x\in \mathbb{R}$:

$$f(x) = \frac{-\cos(2\pi x) + 1}{2}$$

$$n(x) = \frac{-\cos(2\pi x) - 1}{2}$$

$$m(x) = 1$$